# Performing binary comparison of MySQL field values with SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Trying to figure out the best way of handling this:

given a table with 2 fields: id and data 
I would like to select 2 records from this table and perform a binary comparison on the value of the data field for each record using SQL. Any suggestions on how best to do this?

Database being used is MySQL

Comment: What do you want to archieve with this? Do you want to find duplicates? Do you want to store the differences?

Comment: I would just like it to return a 1 or 0 if it matched or not

Comment: Please show us some sample data and the expected result.  Also, what's the criteria for selection of these 2 records?  What exactly do you mean by "*binary comparison*"?  So far your question is too vague.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

MySQL has a [`CAST` function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/cast-functions.html#function_cast). The usage in your case would be something like this:

```sql
SELECT whatever
FROM my_table
WHERE id = CAST(data AS BINARY);
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/26455492/632951 if you are interested in performance.

Comment: Thanks William for improving my answer! It needed updating :)

Comment: Thank you Winston for the update to using `CAST`. It's a better solution.