# MySQL byte-for-byte comparison, which is faster? binary vs bin_collate

Tags: mysql, sql, web

Assume we have a table that looks like this:

```
create table t1(c1 varchar(x)collate utf8mb4_general_ci, index(c1))
```

To do byte-sensitive comparisons, we basically have two ways (assume that **all** relevant strings do **not** have trailing spaces, i.e. they are all [padspace-compliant](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/char.html#docheader)):

```
select*from t1 where c1 ='test'collate utf8mb4_bin

select*from t1 where c1 = binary'test'
```

Which should be preferred when performance is of concern?

When using an index of non-binary character collation, is it faster to [compare](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-collation-expressions.html) with [binary string](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/binary-varbinary.html) or binary collation?

(Adding a new column to the table just to store the binary equivalent of `c1` is a big hit on storage and not possible.)

(P.S. Would appreciate an answer that compares both hash and btree comparisons, although I'm primarily interested in btree comparison.)

Comment: In your testing so far, what have you found?

Comment: adding an index to c1 might be an improvement, if performance is of concern; also, what kind of possible values can c1 have? could they fit into an enum? perhaps you have to add a column with preprocessed variant of c1?

Comment: That the numbers are quirky and near enough to come to any conclusion using one-sided tests. @Ashalynd, The index is already `utf8mb4_general_ci`. The stored values are "english words" though users may type random characters into it, even chinese characters.

Comment: did you run explain on both queries? I wonder if that index even gets used in the second variant.

Comment: perhaps you can introduce another index for binary collation?

Comment: One nice trick that shows good results for me is to allow index usage without the binary matching, and add the binary matching as a second constraint: `SELECT * FROM t1 WHERE c1 = 'test' AND BINARY c1 = 'test';` This way index usage is guaranteed, and narrows down the search significantly, then the binary condition filters out anything that is not exactly matching

Comment: @Galz, Wow that's a good hack, but the question still stands: After we have narrowed down the rows, Is casting to binary string faster or is casting to binary collation faster? Which option should we use?

Comment: @Ashalynd, Maintaining extra indexes is expensive when unnecessary. Especially so in MySQL when we have to create a new column specifically for it, doubling not just index storage, but data storage; see  http://stackoverflow.com/q/6199440/632951 and http://dev.mysql.com/worklog/task/?id=826 . Besides, this is a "binary cast" vs "collate cast" question.

Comment: @Pacerier - Sorry, I don't know which is faster :) From my experience narrowing down the results by good index usage is far more important than optimizing any calculation or manipulation of a single row's data. This is why this nice hack works very well on huge tables... I hope someone else around here can provide the answer you are looking for.

Comment: @Ashalynd, With the casting done on the right side of the comparison, `explain` shows possible_keys c1 for both select statements http://i.stack.imgur.com/fs5VK.png . However, there may be some differences between the **actual way** the index is used.

Answer (score 1):

As you have index in the table,for binary match use binary for constant,not to the column. This will be faster than both of your options.

```
select * from t1 where c1 = binary 'test'
```

Answer to you question is option 1 will be faster where you are doing

```
WHERE c1 collate utf8mb4_bin='test'
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I've updated the question to put the casting on the right side (as opposed to the left side). So with the casting on the right side for both cases, Is casting to binary string faster or is casting to binary collation faster?

Comment: Ok..Great.. In this case Collation will be faster. But I will prefer binary as it will exclude the values like 'test '(with trailing space) and collation will include that. But if your requirement is to include 'test ' as well then go ahead with collation

Comment: Binary conversion of a character takes more space than the collated binary of a varchar value. This link might help. [link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-binary-collations.html)

Comment: Yes the input is assumed to be coherent with [padspace](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/char.html) behavior (in other words, the input is assumed to have no trailing spaces). Btw, when you say "collation will be faster", do you have any tests or links/docs supporting that claim?

Comment: See my previous comment there will be link which says Binary takes more space than Collation _Bin @Pacerier

Comment: Are you talking about trailing spaces?